# Simple Eclipse IDE Java Program

Tags: java

Code a complete Java program to  the following:

- if it is a red light violation, then the fine is 1.75 % of the driver annual salary
- if it is a speeding violation, then the fine is 1.2 %of the annual salary plus .5% of the salary for every 1 mile/hour over the speed limit.

What you need to do?

- prompt user/officer to enter the full name of the driver
- prompt officer to enter his/her full name.
- prompt user/officer to enter annual salary of the driver.
- prompt the officer to enter the type of violation (1 for red light or 2 for speeding)
- if speeding then prompt user to enter how many miles/hour over speed limit.
- evaluate with a set of if...else how much fine should be assessed, then print a full report including:

  - name of officer
  - name of driver
  - annual salary
  - violation type (you need to spell it out not just 1 or 2. (Red Light or Speeding)
  - amount of fine assessed (print a $ sign and round to two decimals)

Also, you must consider the following:

- your program must not accept any code other than 1 or 2 for violation type.
- your input must be handled by different methods and not in main()
- evaluating the fine must be handled in a method of its own.
- report must be handled by a different method.
- the whole program must repeat for a new driver.

Extra credits: develop your own solution when a driver is subject to both violation…caught speeding and passing when red

---

Here is my code:

```
package FinFines_
import java.util.Scanner;

/*
* Description: This program assesses fines for traffic violations.
*/
public class FinFines_
{
    static Scanner get = new Scanner(System.in);
    //declarations:
    static double mph = 0;
    static double salary = 0;
    static double fines = 0;
    static int violation = 0;
    static int answer = 1; //1 to continue or 0 to quit
    static String officer = " ";
    static String driver = " ";

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        //input:
        while (answer != 0) //while will allow the program to repeat for a new driver
        {
            input(officer, driver, salary, violation); //call input method

            //calculations:
            fines = calculateFines(violation, fines, salary, mph); //call calculateFines method

            //Output:   
            disp(officer, driver, salary, violation,fines); //call disp method

            //ask user if they would like to continue
            System.out.println("Would you like to write a new ticket? Press 1 for yes or 0 for no: ");
            answer = get.nextInt();
    }//end while

    System.out.println("Goodbye!");


}//end main
//=================================================================
public static void input(String officer, String driver, double salary, int violation) //Input Method
{
    System.out.println("Officer, please enter your first and last name: ");
    officer = get.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please the driver's first and last name: ");
    driver = get.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter the driver's salary: ");
    salary = get.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Press 1 if the driver ran a red light. Press 2 if the driver was speeding. Press 3 if the driver is subject to both violations. ");
    violation = get.nextInt();
    System.out.println("How many miles per hour was the driver going over the speed limit?: ");
    mph = get.nextDouble();

}//end input
//=================================================================
public static double calculateFines(int violation, double fines, double salary, double mph) //calculates the amount of fines for either violation
{
    {
        if (violation == 1)
            return (salary * 1.75);
        else if (violation == 2)
            return (salary * 1.2) + (mph * .5 * salary);
        else if (violation == 3)
            return (salary * 1.75) + ((salary * 1.2) + (mph * .5 * salary));
        return 0;
    }   
}//end calculateFines
//=================================================================
public static void disp(String officer, String driver, double salary, int violation, double fines) //Display Method
{
    System.out.println ("Your name is Officer " + officer + "\nThe name of the driver you pulled over is: " + driver);
    System.out.println ( String.format( "The driver's annual salary is $%.2f", + salary) );
    {
        if (violation == 1)
        System.out.println("\nThe type of traffic violation the driver received: Red Light");
            else if (violation == 2)
                System.out.println("\nThe type of traffic violation the driver received: Speeding");
            else if (violation == 3)
                System.out.println("\nThe type of traffic violation the driver received: Red Light & Speeding");
    }
    System.out.println ( String.format( "The amount of fines that will be assessed is $%.2f", + fines) );
}//end disp
     }//end class FinFines_
```

---

Here is my issue:

1. When I input values for my program, the program acts as if I didn't input any names or numbers. All it says is
   "Your name is Officer  
   The name of the driver you pulled over is:  
   The driver's annual salary is $0.00
   The amount of fines that will be assessed is $0.00"
   What can I do to make sure the program holds my inputted values?
2. When I press 1, to continue, it skips the first line when it asks for the officer's name. It doesn't allow me to input a name for the variable.
   What can I do to make sure my program doesn't skip this line?
3. Is there an issue with my "return 0;" statement? If I don't include that statement then my program can't run, but I worry that me including it is making my program give 0 to all values.

Comment: You should do some research about mixing `nextLine()` with `nextInt()` and `nextDouble()`.

Comment: Could you include a link? My professor instructed us to write it in that way so I don't know it was incorrect.

Comment: Using them isn't the problem. You just have to be careful about newline characters which are left in the input buffer. These cause the behavior you see. If a previous read doesn't consume the new line character, then the following read will see it and assume that there is no input.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. This is causing my problem #2? When I tell the program to run again, and it not allowing me enter the officer's name for the first line.

Comment: What do you mean by "run the program again"? Does your program actually exit or are you giving input within your program to repeat the processing?

Comment: Line 34 says "//ask user if they would like to continue
            System.out.println("Would you like to write a new ticket? Press 1 for yes or 0 for no: ");
            answer = get.nextInt();" So when I press 1, the program runs again.

Comment: You really are not running your program again since it does not exit and restart. Although...I'm not sure of a better wording, either. I just wanted to clarify the ambiguity.

Comment: My apologies with my verbage. I'm saying I'm able to input new values when I press 1

Comment: As I state in my answer, this is the exact same issue as #1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that in the `calculateFines()` method, you have multiplied your values by 1.75. This will give 175% of the original. To find 1.75%, you need to multiply by 0.0175. This is also applicable for all other values.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Though not a good practice to make everything `static`. Yet to just make your code work change all your methods as following -

```
public static void input(String officer, String driver, double salary, int violation) //Input Method {
```

to

```
public static void input() {
```

---

```
public static double calculateFines(int violation, double fines, double salary, double mph) //calculates the amount of fines for either violation {
```

to

```
public static double calculateFines() {
```

---

```
public static void disp(String officer, String driver, double salary, int violation, double fines) //Display Method {
```

to

```
public static void disp() {
```

---

This would ensure all your static fields are updated as you call these methods using the same parameters within thei definition and now your `main()` would include

```
while (answer != 0) {
    input(); 
    fines = calculateFines(); //call calculateFines method
    disp();  
    System.out.println("Would you like to write a new ticket? Press 1 for yes or 0 for no: ");
        answer = get.nextInt();
}
```

***Note*** - I've cut short the text and removed comments, please do keep them in your code.

Comment: This fixed my problem #1, thank you! Why shouldn't one make everything static? What would be an alternative to my mistake? Do you also know how to fix my problem #2? When I push 1 to continue the program again, it doesn't allow me to input a name for the officer (line 1).

Comment: A better approach would be to define Objects as Officer, Driver etc, which would have individual attributes like name,  speed.. and then use getter and setters from the same to build the logic around their attributes.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to read about the behavior of `nextLine()`, `nextInt()`, and `nextDouble()` regarding new line characters. If any of these leaves a newline character in the input buffer, then the following one will see that character and not consume any further input. This is what you are seeing.

   To fix the issue, you need to read the newline character from the `Scanner` and ignore it. You should look at [the Javadocs for `Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) to find an appropriate method to do this.
2. This is the same issue as #1.
3. Most likely there is no problem with this return as long as the `if` statements account for all possible values of `violation`. In fact, this is a very good solution because it will immediately let you see when `violation` has an invalid value. You should also learn about enums which allow you to define a finite number of choices for a variable.

Comment: I believe someone else stated the same thing as your first comment. Is there any links to a resolution for this issue? I'm not sure what to do to fix that issue. All I know is the problem exists.

Comment: @Stackerr Yes, I posted a comment to your question and am expanding some in an answer. See my edit for a hint about a solution.

Comment: Ok, So I understand that the next command is blocking further input. Based on the article, it seems like I have to reset it using a reset method command?

Comment: @Stackerr More correctly, nextInt() attempts input and sees a newline character. This signals empty input. You need another method which reads a single character in order to prices past the newline character.

Comment: Im racking my brain for this answer. I need a method that ignores the newline character from the Scanner. Could I use the void remove () method to clear the token in the input?

Comment: @user7484936 No, if you read the docs, you see that Scanner does not implement remove() to do anything meaningful. This is actually easier than you think. You just need to read the input to get the newline character.